# Can I delete a paid DLC and re-download it? Ps3

Tags: borderlands-2

I have recently downloaded a DLC for Borderlands 2.
It seems to be not working, am I able to delete and re-download it, if I have paid for it?

Comment: Do not use tags in question title. What platform are you playing on? Steam? Console?

Comment: Not really sure what platform you're referring to, but generally, yes, when you buy DLC, you own it, and can re-download it as you need to.

Answer (score 3):

For the PS3: **Yes**.

I can't find any specific articles from Sony about dlc specifically, but I can personally confirm that you can do this.

[Here's a support article walking you through redownloading a purchase](https://support.us.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/488/~/redownload-playstation-store-content-on-ps3), and this applies to dlc too.

It might also be helpful to know that [you can have it on 2 separate devices simultaneously](http://faq.en.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5656/~/system-activation-and-deactivation) as well. So if you somehow find yourself activating it on multiple devices, you *can* find yourself unable to redownload it if you try to exceed the 2 device limit.